# Python Socket Port Use

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to set a server application and client application in which the server will listen for connections using localhost and a certain port - however - if for example, the port is 2001 - if that port is not available, I would like to use 2002, if that's not available then 2003 - etc. How do I implement that in my code?

```
example = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
example.bind(("localhost",2001))
```

Comment: you can use `example.bind(address, port)` inside a `try` -`except`....

Answer (score 2):

may be just loop around till it doesnt generate an exception

```
port = 2001
while True:
    try:
        example.bind(("localhost",port))
    except:
        port += 1
        continue
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to find an available free port in some kind of loop you can bind to port `0` (*zero*) and let your OS bind to a suitable free port. You can then access the bound port via introspecting the server socket object using `socket.getsockname()`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to bind the socket to a random port number assigned by the kernel and then query for the port number opened.

```
example.bind((host,0)) #0-random, free port number
example.getsockname()
```